# SQL Server Stored Procedure to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to convert a SQL Server stored procedure to MySQL, found this tool: http://www.sqlines.com/online but after the conversion Workbench gives me an error with the DELIMITER saying that it is not valid at this position: create expected.

Unfortunately the SQL Server database cannot be migrated so I need to convert the entire code of this procedure - is there an easy way of converting this or has anyone an idea why I get the DELIMITER error?

```
        DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE CreateQuestionnairForCourse (

p_courseId bigint,
p_openDate bigint /* = 1573884000 */, -- 16 Nov 2019
p_closeDate bigint /* = 1575150900 */,  -- 30 Nov 2019
   
p_servey_etalon bigint /* =20 */,  -- Greek English together
p_questionnair_etalon bigint/* =20 */)

sp_lbl:

BEGIN
DECLARE NOT_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;
   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.


DECLARE v_surveyId bigint;
DECLARE v_questionnairId bigint;
DECLARE v_courseModuleId bigint;
DECLARE v_sequence longtext;
DECLARE v_section bigint;
DECLARE v_added bigint;
DECLARE v_questionId bigint;
DECLARE v_new_questionId bigint;
DECLARE v_IsVisible tinyint DEFAULT 1

declare curs cursor local;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET NOT_FOUND = 1;;


if p_courseId = 0 then
   LEAVE sp_lbl;
end if;
ELSE

      DECLARE v_UnixTS bigint DEFAULT [dbo].[DTtoUnixTS](NOW());

      BEGIN TRAN T1;

       INSERT INTO mdl_questionnaire_survey
       (
          `name`,
          `courseid`,
          `realm`,
          `status`,
          `title`,
          `email`,
          `subtitle`,
          `info`,
          `theme`
       )
        SELECT
         name,
         p_courseId,
         'private',
         `status`,
         title,
         email,
         subtitle,
         info,
         theme
      FROM mdl_questionnaire_survey
      WHERE id =  p_servey_etalon;
              
      SET v_surveyId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

      INSERT INTO mdl_questionnaire
            (`course`,
            `name`,
            intro,
            `qtype` ,
            `respondenttype`,
            `resp_eligible`,
            `resp_view`,
            `opendate`,
            `closedate`,
            `resume`,
            `navigate`,
            `grade`,
            `sid`
            )
         Select
            p_courseId,
            name,
            intro,  
            qtype,respondenttype,
            resp_eligible,
            resp_view,
            p_openDate,
            p_closeDate,
            resume,
            navigate,
            grade,
            v_surveyId
         FROM mdl_questionnaire
         WHERE id=p_questionnair_etalon;
                 
      SET v_questionnairId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

      fast_forward for
      select id  
      FROM `mdl_questionnaire_question`
      where deleted='n' and survey_id=p_servey_etalon   
      open curs;
      fetch next from; curs into v_questionId

         while Not_found = 0
         do         
      
            
            INSERT INTO mdl_questionnaire_question (survey_id,name ,type_id,result_id,`length`,`precise`,`position` ,`content` ,`required` ,`deleted`)
            SELECT v_surveyId,`name`,`type_id` ,`result_id`,`length`,`precise`,`position` ,`content` ,`required` ,`deleted`
            FROM mdl_questionnaire_question where id = v_questionId;
           
            SET v_new_questionId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
         

            INSERT INTO mdl_questionnaire_quest_choice
            SELECT v_new_questionId    
              ,`content`
              ,`value`
           FROM mdl_questionnaire_quest_choice where question_id = v_questionId;           

           fetch next from; curs into v_questionId
         end while;
      
      CLOSE curs;


      SELECT TOP 1 id INTO v_section from mdl_course_sections where course=p_courseId
      ORDER By id ASC;

      INSERT INTO mdl_course_modules  
      (
         course,
         module,
         instance,
         section,
         idnumber,
         added,
         score,
         indent,
         visible,
         visibleold,
         groupmode,
         groupingid,
         -- groupmembersonly,
         completion,
         completionview,
         completionexpected,
         `showdescription`,
         `availability`
      )
      VALUES (
         p_courseId,
         23,
         v_questionnairId,
         v_section,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         v_IsVisible,
         v_IsVisible,
         0,
         0,
         -- 0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         ''
      );

      SET v_courseModuleId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   
      SELECT  sequence INTO v_sequence from mdl_course_sections where id = v_section;
        
      if v_sequence = '' then
         SET v_sequence = CAST(v_courseModuleId as varchar(1));
      ELSE
         SET v_sequence = Concat(v_sequence , ','  , CAST(v_courseModuleId as varchar(1)));
      end if; -- COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  
         
      UPDATE mdl_course_sections
      SET sequence = v_sequence
      WHERE id=v_section;

      

      UPDATE mdl_course
                   SET cacherev = (;CASE
                       WHEN cacherev IS NULL THEN v_UnixTS
                       WHEN cacherev < v_UnixTS THEN v_UnixTS
                       WHEN cacherev > v_UnixTS + 3600 THEN v_UnixTS
                       ELSE cacherev + 1 END) WHERE id = p_courseId


   COMMIT; T1;

   END;

END IF;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do you *really* need a `CURSOR`?

Comment: Unfortunately, i do

Comment: Also, why are you using `varchar(1)`s? Why would you ever need a variable length string of length 1? `char(1)` would be much better. Looking briefly(ish) at your code, would seem (in SQL Server) you could achieve what you want with an`OUTPUT` and `INTO` clause, rather than a `CURSOR`. I don't know if MySQL supports such functionality.

Comment: the above code is the output of the conversion from mssql to mysql using the tool mentioned, seems that varchar(1) was done from the converter, in my code is just varchar

Comment: *"in my code is just varchar"* That's even worse... Just `varchar` in SQL Server can mean different things depending on the usage. As a result you are almost certainly going to end up with truncation issues. This is why you should convert your own code (as the converter has had to assume due to the poorly written T-SQL), and **always** declare your lengths, scales and precisions.

Comment: Demonstration of what happens with `varchar` with no length: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a06ec8c1d09f10e1c3ec1e6b3b0662a)

Comment: _When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If n isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30._ - from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I would also suggest that you exercise extreme caution with SP automatic code conversion between DB engines. There are a lot of edge cases (null handling, implicit data type conversion in functions, etc.) which may subtly affect your query execution e.g. affect returned record counts. If you do not know both DB engines enough to spot these issues, you probably should not do the conversion, or you will be chasing bugs for years to come.

Comment: If you read [MySQL tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx) you can see that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` work differently for multi-row inserts, yet [your tool](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-mysql#built-in-sql-functions) assumes they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

for my eye, the problem is comments in your code. It might be the conversion tool can't handle /* = whatewer.. */

Also after conversions refactor code as per suggestions - varchar(1) is always a bad idea... And in your case probably it is also wrong as I would expect the course module will be longer than 1 char converting from int...